# removing a list item from a list after dropping it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am messing around with some code, and I have a list  which I have applied the draggable function to, and another div with a drop function.

what I am trying to achieve is when the list element is dropped it is removed from the parent list and added to another list.

here is the code I was playing with:

```
    <div id='dAvail'>
<ul>
    <li><div class='abox'>1</div></li>
    <li><div class='abox'>2</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id='somewhereToDrop'>
</div>
<div id='newListHere'>
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//add the droppable function to the divs in main list
$('#dAvail ul).each(function(){
   $('li>div).draggable();
});

$('#somewhereToDrop').droppable({
   tolerance:'touch',
   drop:function(event,ui){
   //this is where I am having problems.
   //if I do ui.draggable I get an object representing the object I dragged but not 100% how to remove said object from the orginal list to then append to the new one.
   //this is what i tried.
   var t = ui.draggable[0]; //represents the div that i dropped.
   $(t).parent().parent().remove($(t).parent());
   //that is as far as I have gotten as this returns an error


});
```

if anyone could point out how to get to remove that object from the list it would be great.
I even tried to see if I could do $(t).parent().eq() but that did not work, the idea was to get the list index then remove it like that.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove()` does not take a parameter. It removes its instance from the DOM. So, really, all you want to do is:

```
$(t).parent().remove();
```

Comment: thank you. i figured out that i dont actually want to call remove at all but just append it to the new list, but this helped me work out how to get there.

Comment: If you do not want to completely remove, try .detach() instead. It'll return the object, and keep it in memory, but remove it from the DOM. This allows you to reinsert it later one should you want to.